# How to define the corner points

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

There is a picture on which I want to cut off 6 frames automatically:

[image]

For this I need to learn the corner points of the frame, but I do not know how to do it. The points that I need to determine are marked with black lines here:

[image]

---

Or maybe someone knows a program for automatic sprite cutting?

Comment: **I want to get it** https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Bh1.png

Comment: **I want to get it automatically** https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Bh1.png

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: yes it is, solved

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not right way for cutting image.

Its better create standard rectangle and using key mask to removing background color.

Its better designer tell you the points.

By the way if you want to find out automatically:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826377/Rapid-Object-Detection-in-Csharp

https://kishordgupta.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/detect-object-from-image-based-on-object-color-by-c/

Answer (score 1):

A fully automatic solution would involve scanning the image for filled pixels. Hard, slow and unreliable. Not recommended.

The best way imo is a **semi-automatic** solution.

Add a few (6) `NumericUpDowns` (or `TrackBars`) to control the

- StartX and StartY
- rectangle Width and Height and
- Width and Height of the gaps

Draw rectangles over the image to control the result on each value change.

When happy you cut out the images.

The big advantage is that all rectangles will have the same size, as they usually should for sprites. And you can control the margins..

Here is an example at work unsing trackbar sliders:

[image]

BTW: your 'spritemap' is not well made as the sprites will not have the same sizes; so they will have to be cut out individually. Clearly against the normal way of spritemaps.

Comment: The problem isn't hard or slow or unreliable as long as the sprites are seperated from each other. You just need a *Flood fill* algorithm. It does however need a lot of work.

Comment: ??? a) Floodfill seems entirely unrelated and b) it is not a lot of work. wikipedia has a few nice an simple algorithms and one could even resort to some old gdi calls. But: It is in no way I can see related. Also: The sprites may well consist of unconnected parts, bound to fail fully automatic solutions..

Comment: In animation there are no unconnected parts meaning your model is **always** continuous. If not then you can not have dynamic force, movement simulation or your sprite is corrupt. The flood fill algorithm can be used to find min max in both x-y axies.

Comment: Are you sure you actually read and understood the question???